# Odd error: Error in PredictMat(object$smooth[[k]], data) : , `by' variable must be same dimension as smooth arguments

Tags: r, statistics, mgcv

I'm getting an error in mgcv, and I can't figure out where it comes
from.  The setup is the following:  I've got a fitted GAM object called
"MI", and a vector of "prediction data" (with default values for
predictors).  I feed this into `predict.gam(object, newdata = whatever)`
via the following function:

```
makepred = function(varstochange,val){
     for (i in 1:length(varstochange)){
         if (varstochange[i] == "pot.trial"){j=1}
         if (varstochange[i] == "year"){j=2}
         if (varstochange[i] == "crop.legume"){j=3}
         if (varstochange[i] == "crop.fruit"){j=4}
         if (varstochange[i] == "feedstock"){j=5}
         if (varstochange[i] == "BCAR.imp"){j=8}
         if (varstochange[i] == "INAR.imp"){j=9}
         if (varstochange[i] == "bcph.imp"){j=10}
         if (varstochange[i] == "phi.imp"){j=11}
         if (varstochange[i] == "htt.imp"){j=12}
         if (varstochange[i] == "bc.prc.C.imp"){j=13}
         if (varstochange[i] == "CEC.imp"){j=14}
         if (varstochange[i] == "soc.imp"){j=15}
         if (varstochange[i] == "sand.imp"){j=16}
         if (varstochange[i] == "clay.imp"){j=17}
         if (varstochange[i] == "abslat.imp"){j=18}
         preddat[j] = val[i]
         }
     predict.gam(MI,newdata=preddat,se.fit=TRUE)
     }
```

I then make predictions that look like this:

```
a = makepred(c("phi.imp","bcph.imp","year"),c(4.5,7.25,1))
b = makepred(c("phi.imp","bcph.imp","year"),c(5.5,7.25,1))
c = makepred(c("phi.imp","bcph.imp","year"),c(6.5,7.25,1))
d = makepred(c("phi.imp","bcph.imp","year"),c(7.5,7.25,1))
makepHplot(a,b,c,d,title="1st harvest, BC pH = 7.25")
```

where "makepHplot" is a different function that I made.

This worked for quite some time.  Then I added some data to the model
and changed the specification slightly.  Now I'm getting this error message:

```
1> a = makepred(c("bcph.imp","year"),c(7.5,1))
Error in PredictMat(object$smooth[[k]], data) :
   `by' variable must be same dimension as smooth arguments
```

I never got this message with the old fitted model (and still don't).
What is happening?  I don't know what the error message means and I can't figure out what about the new fitted model
is causing this problem.  Typing "PredictMat" isn't helping me, nor is
Google.  The problem isn't that all of the variables aren't in the
prediction data.

Would appreciate any help here.

(Apologies for cross-posting on R-help)

Its also worth noting that I'm fitting this model several times after imputing missing data, then combining the output using Rubin's rules.  But that shouldn't be relevant -- I get the same error using any one of the constituent fitted models, rather than the combined version.

**PROBLEM SOLVED:**  The problem was that `trialid`, a factor variable, had levels that did not include "1".  When I set `trialid` in `preddat` to something else, it worked. The way I set up my model, interacting the random effect with a dummy =0, this variable has no effect, but mgcv still needs it to do the prediction.

Comment: You haven't shown how you fitted the GAM with **mgcv**. Can you show that code too please

Comment: Edited.  What are you looking for?  For my part, I don't even know what the error means.

Comment: What is `preddat` at the *start* of `makepred`, it doesn't seem defined. Also, you GAM is hugely complex, with many terms, but I don't see you supplying those as variables as `newdata` in the `predict` call. All variables mentioned in the formula must be supplied as `newdata`, including variables used in `by` terms and in `bs = "re"` smooths. Does `makepred` supply **all** variables used in the model?

Comment: `Preddat` is a vector of "default" values.  It gets modified by `makepred`.  Preddat has all of the values that are in the dataset.  

I don't think that I've messed up anything like this, its my guess that there is some small, stupid code wrinkle somewhere.  Mostly I want to know what the error message means.  Its not clear.

Comment: Well this is where your terminology is letting things down and why we ask for reproducible examples or at least all the relevant code or information on the structure of objects used. You don't pass `newdata` a vector, it needs a data frame. The only person who can probably tell you what the error means is Simon Wood. However, the times I've been hit by similar errors is when I've not supplied all the variables used in model fitting to `newdata`. Hence I can see how the error might be raised and I'm asking for the extra info so I can fully understand what your are trying to do.

Comment: What changed in the specification of the model? I'd start there and see if you have forgotten a variable that is now in the model but which is not in the `preddat` object. Next I'd look at the data; is there something off in the levels now for variables used in `by` terms?

Comment: Gavin, thanks for your help.  I figured out the problem -- indeed it was a silly little wrinkle.  The error message makes sense now -- there was effectively an interaction between the random effect and the "dum" variable, but the random effect, a factor, didn't include 1 as preddat did.